# How to prevent output for a shell script command

Tags: shell

What does `tee` do and is it possible to run this command in a alternative way with suppressing the output?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

is an indirect way of saying:

```
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

as root.

You see the output on the terminal because of the [tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448043/how-does-the-posix-tee-command-work) command.

You can rewrite it as below, to suppress the output, while running as non-root user:

```
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" | sudo sh -c "cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
```

---

See also:

- [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied

Comment: That's a rare case of finding a fault in Benjamin's work :)